# Start and stop in MS Project

Tags: ms-project-2013

I have a lot of situations where there is a small project that is, let's say, 50 percent done.   Then it's completely put on hold, and restarted a month later.   How is it best to accurately reference it in MS Project without splitting it up?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you're saying that project activity is split up by administrative decision, but you don't want project to show it as split?  Shouldn't MS Project reflect reality?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: document and get approval by the project's management committee that adds a milestone at the date where the project is due to start again. Then set upcoming tasks to depend on the milestone.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a choice but to split it up.  Schedule is based on time.  If you stopped the work and have some degree of time in between the stop and when it is restarted, you have a split in the schedule.